Group text and figure so that they page-break together
I have text
[a whole bunch of text up here]

(a.)

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

Because of how the text length ended up, "(a.)" is at the end of a page and the figure is on the next page, when I want them grouped.
I know that I can accomplish this with \pagebreak, but the problem with that is that if I edit text above the break then it will throw the alignment off.
All I really want is: On whatever page one of them occurs, the other one also occurs.  I don't want them split by a page break.
Is there a way to do this so that, even if the text later shifts around because of editing, the text will still be grouped on the same page?

I suggest you enclose both the text label and the tikzpicture material in a minipage environment of width \linewidth.
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
(a.)

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
    \draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (-5,0)--(5,0) node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-5)--(0,5) node[above]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

